# dom2image does not work on ios, edge and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

I have been trying to create a pdf from HTML content(charts). I am using jsPDF.js in combination with `dom2image.js` to create a pdf document. it works well on devices such as desktop, laptop, and android phones but the same function does not run on ios devices(in any browser on ios device including chrome). I am not sure what error even is as I have no way to debug on an iPhone. Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this? The code I am currently using is as below:

```
 let pdf = new jsPDF();
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('chartID'))
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
console.log(dataUrl);
        pdf.addImage(encodeURI(dataUrl),'jpeg', 50, 0, 100, 80); 
 pdf.save();
        });
```

I've already tried `html2canvas` and `html2pdf` libraries with no success.

Comment: From the readme,.. `Safari is not supported, as it uses a stricter security model on <foreignObject> tag. Suggested workaround is to use toSvg and render on the server.`  Also even if you install Chrome on IOS it still uses Apple's rendering engine.

Comment: @Keith I tried as you said but I get the following error: Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData 
    at Object.x.convertStringToImageData (jspdf.min.js:50)
    at Object.x.addImage